# Offset Fetch error in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to test a very simple query.

```
Select * 
from da.swati_testtable
Order by Salary
offset 1 row fetch next 3 row only
```

I tested the first part of the query uptil offset and it works fine. When i include the offset clause, it throws an error that

> SQL command not properly ended and there is an error on the line with
>   the offset code.

Regards
Swati

Comment: Sounds as if you are using an outdated Oracle version. You need at least 12.1 for that to work

Answer (score 0):

You need semicolon at the end of your code and I believe it needs to be ROWS not row

Check here for details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html

```
Select * 
from da.swati_testtable
Order by Salary
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: @SwatiVishwanathan then, your DB version is prior to 12c

Comment: The semicolon or other terminator is a feature of the client application, not the language. `row` and `rows` are synonymous.

Comment: Thanks our Admin confirmed that I have a version older than 12c..thanks

Comment: Most tools display the database version somewhere, and if not you can query `v$version` or `v$instance`.